# A real important dream, like XXX, is worth every possible effort to guard

Tags: sentence

I wrote that sentence in my composition but I really feel that it doesn't sound natural.  What will you write to express the meaning?

Comment: XXX in your heading connotates pornography ;)

Comment: I think only people who are quite familiar with pornography could know that :D

Comment: A "real important" dream? As opposed to an imaginary-but-important dream? Or a dream imagined to be important?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Firstly, use *really*, an **adverb**, instead of *real*, an **adjective**. I'm sure you know the difference, but basically, adverbs describe verbs, adjectives, or other verbs and an adjective describes a noun: *really* describes the adjective *important*, which in turn describes *dream*.

Of course, as *important* is quite a strong word, you could leave out the word *really* altogether.

There is nothing wrong with your phrase 'every possible effort to guard', it is just not idiomatic. You could use a more common turn of phrase, like 'is worth protecting at all costs'.

I would say:

```
An important dream, like one day being Prime Minister,
is worth protecting at all costs.
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd say that *protecting at all costs* is a bit of a cliché. It's fine, but there's no harm in looking for a variant.

The problem with *worth every possible effort to guard* is that the reader is expecting the last word to be *achieve*. The sudden appearance of *guard* throws the reader, who then has to read the sentence again to understand the subtle difference.

*An important dream, such as becoming Prime Minister, is well worth guarding.* The *guard* is still at the end of the sentence, and the construction *is well worth achieving* is still possible, but the reader is less likely to be expecting it, and therefore is less likely to be thrown by encountering *guarding* instead.

*An important dream, such as becoming Prime Minister, should be guarded with every sinew.* Maybe the language here is a bit flowery, but it could be an option, depending on what effect you're going for.

(Note: My use of *such as* instead of *like* is probably just a personal preference.)